# Is an if-let or a normal if condition better?

Tags: rust

For example:

```
fn foo() -> Option<()> {
     // ...
}

fn bar() -> Option<()> {
    if let None = foo() { // <---- here
        return None;
    }
}
```

Then I changed the if-statement to:

```
if None == foo()
```

and it also works.

Is it ok to use `a == b` instead of `if let a = b`?

Comment: I take it as a rule to only use `if let` if I assign/destructure something, so I might write `if let Some(ch) = sc.next() ...` since I get `ch` out of it, but not `if let None = foo(sc)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Echoing and expanding on [Magnus Hoff's point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048629/rust-if-let-vs-normal-if-condition-which-way-is-better#comment61645263_37048629), I only use `if let` when I care about the value being matched against. In this example, I'd use something like [`Option::is_none`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.is_none) to further highlight that I don't care:

```
if foo().is_none() {
```

This has the tiny benefit of sidestepping the requirement for the wrapped `T` to implement `PartialEq`, as [fjh points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37048828/155423).

In my experience however, this *particular* construct is rarely seen because usually you want to do something in the `Some` case. Once you have multiple branches, I upgrade to a `match` statement.

Answer (score 3):

> So my questions is: Is it ok using a == b instead of if let a = b?

Yes, that's absolutely fine.

One thing to note, though, is that the former will only compile if you're working on some type `Option<T>` where `T` implements `PartialEq`, while the latter will work regardless. This is because `Option<T>` only implements `PartialEq` if `T` implements `PartialEq`.