# Is there any performance difference between `if let` and `if` for a boolean?

Tags: if-statement, rust

For example:

```
let mut v = vec![2, 3, 4];
if let false = v.is_empty() {
    v.push(5);
}
```

vs:

```
let mut v = vec![2, 3, 4];
if !v.is_empty() {
    v.push(5);
}
```

My gut feeling is that it's trivial and doesn't matter.

Comment: *Highly* related, if not a dupe: [Is an if-let or a normal if condition better?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37048629/155423)

Comment: Why not `if v.is_empty() == false {}`? It is explicit and has no useless `let`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any performance question, you **need to profile** to be sure. Anything but that is essentially guessing.

As a first-level guess however, you can look at the generated assembly:

```
#![crate_type="lib"]

pub fn one() {
    let mut v = vec![2, 3, 4];
    if let false = v.is_empty() {
        v.push(5);
    }
}

pub fn two() {
    let mut v = vec![2, 3, 4];
    if !v.is_empty() {
        v.push(5);
    }
}
```

Compiling the above code to assembly using Rust 1.18 and diffing the two functions shows minimal differences, mostly around constant and label names:

```
--- a.asm   2017-07-06 13:53:29.000000000 -0400
+++ b.asm   2017-07-06 13:53:48.000000000 -0400
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-_ZN10playground3one17hbd49bc1da7229962E:
-.Lfunc_begin0:
+_ZN10playground3two17h3228f5d5d04f0491E:
+.Lfunc_begin1:
@@ -5 +5 @@
-   .cfi_lsda 27, .Lexception0
+   .cfi_lsda 27, .Lexception1
@@ -7 +7 @@
-.Ltmp8:
+.Ltmp14:
@@ -10 +10 @@
-.Ltmp9:
+.Ltmp15:
@@ -12 +12 @@
-.Ltmp10:
+.Ltmp16:
@@ -18 +18 @@
-   je  .LBB1_8
+   je  .LBB2_8
@@ -23 +23 @@
-   movaps  .LCPI1_0(%rip), %xmm0
+   movaps  .LCPI2_0(%rip), %xmm0
@@ -25 +25 @@
-.Ltmp5:
+.Ltmp11:
@@ -28 +28 @@
-.Ltmp6:
+.Ltmp12:
@@ -36 +36 @@
-   je  .LBB1_4
+   je  .LBB2_4
@@ -40 +40 @@
-.LBB1_4:
+.LBB2_4:
@@ -44 +44 @@
-.LBB1_8:
+.LBB2_8:
@@ -46,2 +46,2 @@
-.LBB1_5:
-.Ltmp7:
+.LBB2_5:
+.Ltmp13:
@@ -51 +51 @@
-   je  .LBB1_7
+   je  .LBB2_7
@@ -56 +56 @@
-.LBB1_7:
+.LBB2_7:
```

To me, that's proof enough that they are the same. I'd still prefer the boolean form because it's easier to understand:

```
let mut v = vec![2, 3, 4];
if !v.is_empty() {
    v.push(5);
}
```

Comment: I understand OP. `!` is not really readable: when you scan quickly the code with the eyes, you can skip this easily. I would have prefered a `not` keyword.

Comment: @Boiethios: I agree, I've always found `!` rather iffy in this position because it's so easy to miss. I mean, the difference between `!v` and `lv`/`iv` isn't exactly striking.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Unfortunately, because of backward compatibility, the team will likely never consider such a breaking change.