# How do I conditionally execute code only when an Option is None?

Tags: rust

I don't want to take action if the function returns a value in the optional; how do I test the `None` case only?  This code works, but it looks horrible.

```
let v = ffunc();
match v {
  None => { callproc() }, 
  Some(x) => {  }
}
```

In C, I can write:

```
int x = ffunc();
if ( !x ) { callproc() }
```

Comment: maybe you want use https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.or_else

Comment: Related: [Is an if-let or a normal if condition better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048629/is-an-if-let-or-a-normal-if-condition-better)

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation

Answer (score 87, accepted):

If you are not interested in the value, just use [`Option::is_none()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.is_none), or its counterpart [`Option::is_some()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.is_some):

```
if v.is_none() { ... }
```

Answer (score 65):

To check if an `Option` is `None` you can either use `Option::is_none` or use the `if let` syntax.

For example:

```
let x = ffunc();

if let None = x {
    println!("x is None")
}
```

Or using the `Option::is_none` function:

```
let x = ffunc();

if x.is_none() {
    println!("x is None")
}
```

Comment: or `if x == None`.

Comment: @Shepmaster Only iff `T` in `Option<T>` implements `PartialEq`.

Answer (score 33):

To complete the answer above, if the option is `Some(x)`:

```
let v = ffunc()
if let Some(x) = v {
    func_to_use_x(x);
} else {
    callproc();
}
```

If you don't care about the value in the option, then:

```
if v.is_none() {...}
```

or

```
if v.is_some() {...}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to insert a value *into* the `Option` if it's `None`, and get the value otherwise, you can use `get_or_insert`

```rust
let mut x = None;
let y = x.get_or_insert(5);

assert_eq!(y, &5);
assert_eq!(x, Some(5));
```

Or `get_or_insert_with` for lazily evaluation:

```rust
let mut x = None;
let y = x.get_or_insert_with(|| 5);

assert_eq!(y, &5);
assert_eq!(x, Some(5));
```

You can also use `or` and `or_else` to return a new `Option`, instead of mutating the original:

```rust
let x = None;
assert_eq!(x.or(Some(100)), Some(100));

let x = None;
assert_eq!(x.or_else(|| Some(100)), Some(100));
```

Answer (score 3):

The [**let-else**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/rust-by-example/flow_control/let_else.html) syntax introduced with version 1.65 of Rust makes the OP's problem look the least bloated:

```
let None = ffunc() else { return; };
callproc();
```