# How do I idiomatically convert an Option to a bool in Rust in a one liner?

Tags: rust

An option can be converted to a bool using the following code :

```rust
match some_opt {
    Some(_) => true,
    None => false,
}
```

Is there a more concise one-liner way to do this ?

Comment: As the answer says, `Option` has `is_some()` and `is_none()`. If you need a similar one-liner for enums other than `Option`, you can use [the `matches!` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.matches.html) - for `Option` it'd be `matches!(some_opt, Some(_))`.

Comment: To convert in the other direction, from `bool` to `Option`, you can use the `then()` method (or `then_some()` on nightly).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I conditionally execute code only when an Option is None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53177980/how-do-i-conditionally-execute-code-only-when-an-option-is-none)

Comment: Even though the reply is the same the question is quite different semantically speaking

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`Option::is_some`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.is_some) or [`Option::is_none`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.is_none)

```rust
some_opt.is_some()
some_opt.is_none()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to map the `Option<T>` to a `bool` and also consider it in your boolean expression, you can use [`map_or()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or):

```rust
some_opt.map_or(false, |x| map_to_bool(x))
```

Note:

- `map_to_bool()` represents any user-defined mapping function that returns a `bool`.

An [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=67c31b7523b1deeb1d4eff5cd524f353):

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq)]
enum Either {
    Left,
    Right,
}
    
fn main() {
    let is_left = |e: Either| e == Either::Left;
    assert_eq!(None.map_or(false, is_left), false);
    assert_eq!(Some(Either::Right).map_or(false, is_left), false);
    assert_eq!(Some(Either::Left).map_or(false, is_left), true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Rust 1.70.0, if you want to convert `Option` to `bool` but also consider the value in the `Some`, you should not use `map_or()` but [`is_some_and()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.is_some_and):

```rust
some_opt.is_some_and(|x| value_to_bool(x))
```