# How to Properly Assert Not Null in Rust Tests?

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I'm writing some Rust tests for my project and want to ensure that my MongoStorage struct initializes successfully.

Here's my test code in Rust:

```rust
#[test]
fn creates_storage_successfully() {
  let storage = MongoStorage::new();
  if Some(storage).is_some()  {
    println!("Database connection established successfully");
  } else {
    eprintln!("Failed to establish a database connection");
  }
}
```

But it looks verbose and doesn't use `assert` functions. I believe it would be great to check if the variable is not `null` in one line. Moreover, I would like to use one of the `assert` functions suitable for tests instead of print statements. However, I couldn't find a similar function like:

```rust
assert_ne!(storage, null)
```

Maybe I'm heading in the wrong direction, or perhaps there's a more convenient way to check such cases in Rust?

Comment: I'm confused, `Some(storage)` is always `Some`, why would you need to assert that it is so? Sounds tautological...

Comment: Rust doesn't have "null" for arbitrary types

Comment: Since you're already using `is_some()`, why don't you use `assert!(...is_some())`?

Comment: `Some(x).is_some()` is always true... It's not really clear what you're looking for, doesn't just `assert_ne!(storage, None)` work? or maybe `assert!(storage.is_some())` If `MongoStorage` doesn't return `Option` then it **has to be** properly initialized (unless you have some unsound `unsafe` code somewhere), that's one of the great things about it, you can rid yourself of the fear of `null`, it's always explicit.

Comment: @kmdreko @cafce25  Seems I'm wrong, and checking for "null" isn't a good idea in general. More precisely, I would like to verify that `MongoStorage::new()` works correctly – that it connects to the database without any failures. What is the best way to check it then in rust?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Maybe it is a solution. Thanks

Comment: @VolodyaLombrozo I would expect a method like that would return a `Result` which could communicate the failure, and for testing a simple `MongoStorage::new().expect("should connect to mongo")` would suffice if you expect it to succeed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I conditionally execute code only when an Option is None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53177980/how-do-i-conditionally-execute-code-only-when-an-option-is-none)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no null values in Rust itself, but it seems that your `MongoStorage::new()` returns an `Option<T>` type, so your assert could look like

```
assert_ne!(storage, None);
```

If it doesn't return an `Option<T>`type, it should return an empty storage, so maybe you should check wether is empty or not with a `is_empty()` like function.

Also a `new()` function is usually used for non faulty functions, so if it can fail maybe you should use another name as `build()` or `connect()`; and if it cannot fail I guess it makes no sense to test it.

Comment: Note that this might not work if `storage` does not implement `PartialEq` (i.e. if you can't do `storage == None`).

Answer (score 1):

What does `MongoStorage::new()` return, exactly? In idiomatic Rust, if a function is called `new()`, it cannot fail. In particular since there is no `null` in Rust, you do not need to assert anything, so maybe your test is not necessary?

---

Now, I'm going to assume that it's actually something along the lines of

```rust
let storage = MongoStorage::try_new(); // This returns a `Result<..., ...>`.
```

and you need to check whether `storage` has succeeded or failed.

Option 1:

```rust
assert!(storage.is_ok(), "Oh no, we failed to establish the connection");
```

Option 2:

```rust
assert!(matches!(storage, Ok(_)), "Oh no, we failed to establish the connection");
```

Option 3:

```rust
#[test]
fn creates_storage_successfully() {
  MongoStorage::try_new()
     .expect("Oh no, we failed to establish the connection");
}
```